# Event Tracker with R Shiny Inputs and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, google-analytics

Would somebody know the syntax for tracking events with Google Analytics and R Shiny?

I'd like to track which inputs the user is selecting when interacting with my apps.  So in this example, I'd like to know when a user uses and makes changes to the 'PointUseInput' checkbox input.

I tried following the advice [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/google-analytics.html), but I'm not super familiar with JavaScript, so I'm not sure how to structure the ga function.

```
# ################################################################################################
# ################################################################################################
# # Sec 1a. Needed Libaries & Input Files

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

##The Data
Map_DF <- data.frame("Point_ID" = c("A1", "B1", "C3"), 
                     "Latitude" = c(38.05, 39.08, 40.05), 
                     "Longitude" = c(-107.00, -107.05, -108.00),
                     "PointUse" = c("farm", "house", "well"))


################################################################################################
################################################################################################
#UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
    
    dashboardHeader(), 
    
    dashboardSidebar(
        

       ### tags$head(includeHTML(("google-analytics.html"))),  #Google Analytics html tag here
        
        
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "PointUseInput", label = "Select Point Use", choices = Map_DF$PointUse, selected = Map_DF$PointUse)
    ), 
    
    dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(leafletOutput(outputId = 'mapA'))
    )
)

################################################################################################
################################################################################################
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    ## The Filter
    filterdf <- reactive({
        Map_DF %>% 
            filter(PointUse %in% input$PointUseInput)
    })
    
    ## Base Map Creation
    output$mapA <- renderLeaflet({
        
        leaflet() %>%
            addProviderTiles(
                providers$Esri.DeLorme,
                options = providerTileOptions(
                    updateWhenZooming = FALSE,
                    updateWhenIdle = TRUE)
            ) %>%
            setView(lng = -107.50, lat = 39.00, zoom = 7)
    })
    
    ## Update Map with Filter Selection
    observe({
        leafletProxy("mapA", session) %>% 
            clearMarkers() %>% 
            addCircleMarkers(
                data = filterdf(),
                radius = 10,
                color = "red",
                lat = ~Latitude,
                lng = ~Longitude,
                popupOptions(autoPan = FALSE),
                popup = ~paste("PointUse: ", filterdf()$PointUse))
    })
    
}

################################################################################################
################################################################################################
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

With the accompanying google-analytics JavaScript Code...

```
  $(document).on('change', 'select', function(e) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', value);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the following syntax in the *google-analytics JavaScript Code* worked for me:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

So, instead of:

```
 $(document).on('change', 'select', function(e) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', value);
  });
```

Try:

```
 $(document).on('change', 'select', function(e) {
    gtag('event', 'action', {
     'event_category': 'category',
     'event_label': 'label',
     'value': <value>
    });
  });
```

You could also try:

```
 $('#selectInputId').on('change', function(e) {
    gtag('event', 'action', {
     'event_category': 'category',
     'event_label': 'label',
     'value': <value>
    });
  });
```

That is the only changed I made when following [the same article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/google-analytics.html) you linked to.